# Can I use two different domain names with a WordPress multisite network?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I am currently running a DV server with MediaTemple and would like to have my domains: `abc.com` and `cba.com` mapped to the subdomains I set up with the WP networks `one.mydomain.com` and `two.mydomain.com`. The goal is keep the URLs `abc.com` and `cba.com` viewable in the browser, but the zone files are just referencing the subdomains I have set up.

Sorry if this kinda of confusing, it is a major headache. Any help would great!

Comment: WP Domain Mapping plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

For example, the domain mapping plugin can map the  abc.com to one.mydomain.com and cba.com to two.mydomain.com.  Note that you might need special SSL certificates if you plan on using SSL across different domain names.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go, I'm sure I will get hung up somewhere